# Hibernate findByID implementation

Tags: java, hibernate

I found the following code on net for fetching a object from DB.Now what does lock indicates??
Whe does it lock?

```
public T findById(ID id, boolean lock) {
        T entity;
        if (lock) {
            entity = (T) getSession().load(getPersistentClass(), id, LockMode.UPGRADE);
        } else {
            entity = (T) getSession().load(getPersistentClass(), id);
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just uses the appropriate [Hibernate LockMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LockMode.html). If you have a more specific question, it might be easier to answer.